# Improving Z3 model output for String -> String functions

Tags: python, z3, z3py

Consider the following code specifying a simple function from strings to strings:

```py
from z3 import *
map = Function('map', StringSort(), StringSort())
c1 = map(StringVal('key1')) == StringVal('value1')
c2 = map(StringVal('key2')) == StringVal('value2')
c3 = map(StringVal('key3')) == StringVal('value3')
c4 = map(StringVal('key4')) == StringVal('value4')
s = Solver()
s.add(And(c1, c2, c3, c4))
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

The model output is as follows:

```
[map = [Concat(Unit(Char),
               Concat(Unit(Char),
                      Concat(Unit(Char), Unit(Char)))) ->
        "value1",
        Concat(Unit(Char),
               Concat(Unit(Char),
                      Concat(Unit(Char), Unit(Char)))) ->
        "value2",
        Concat(Unit(Char),
               Concat(Unit(Char),
                      Concat(Unit(Char), Unit(Char)))) ->
        "value3",
        Concat(Unit(Char),
               Concat(Unit(Char),
                      Concat(Unit(Char), Unit(Char)))) ->
        "value4",
        else -> "value1"]]
```

How can I get it to output the actual keys instead of `Concat(Unit(Char), Concat(Unit(Char), ...))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a recent breakage in z3py. If I run your program with z3 compiled on August 3rd 2021 from their GitHub master, I get:

```
sat
[map = ["key2" -> "value2",
        "key3" -> "value3",
        "key4" -> "value4",
        else -> "value1"]]
```

But if I run it with z3 compiled on November 15th 2021, then I see the output you are seeing; which is clearly bogus.

Please report this as a bug at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues

Comment: Strange because I'm using 4.8.12, which was released on July 13th. This is also an issue on 4.8.13.

Comment: Sequence logic had a big rewrite over the summer; where strings and sequences were re-engineered to support the new SMTLib String logic. (It used to be that Strings were simply sequences of 8-bit bit-vectors. This is no longer the case; Now they have their own separate type now supporting unicode.) So, I wouldn't be surprised if things were a bit flaky over the summer with respect to how models were printed. I doubt this is a "big" bug though, once reported they should be able to fix it rather quickly.

Comment: Oh good to know it supports unicode now! I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/5674

Comment: @ahelwer Looks like Nikolaj already fixed the issue in GitHub master. You're going to have to compile from sources until they make a new release.